# JTable cell data showing "..." on column resize

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Two questions:

1.) How do I put a min limit on column resize in JTable?

2.) How do I stop data from showing a "..." on column resize when data can't fit into cell?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Minimum width 100 for first column
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(100);
```

About the `...`, I am not sure you can do anything but keeping the minimum width of the cell according to its value.